# Como pegar o caminho do executável aberto em C

Tags: c, arquivo, path

Como posso capturar o caminho do executável em C e colocá-lo dentro de uma *string*?

Comment: É Linux ou Windows?

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Se ainda não o fez, veja o [tour] como fazer isso. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando a melhor solução para você. Só pode aceitar apenas uma delas, mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 5):

Se quer o caminho e não o nome apenas, não tem uma forma padrão universal. Terá que consultar o sistema operacional e cada um tem seu jeito. Como não foi informado, indicarei os 2 principais:

Linux:

```
readlink("/proc/self/exe", buf, bufsize)
```

[Documentação](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/readlink.2.html).

Windows

```
GetModuleFileName(NULL, buf, bufsize)
```

[Documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getmodulefilenamea?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/IO/GetPath.c).

O `argv[0]` fornece apenas `./nome`, na maioria das vezes, pode até fornecer o caminho se for chamado de outros lugares específicos, mas não se pode confiar que será chamado do local adequado para fornecer a resposta que se espera. Além disso o código em que se precisa desta informação pode não ter acesso a essa variável (está fora do `main()` e não foi passada à frente de alguma forma). Portanto só funciona em situações bem específicas.

Answer (score 4):

A função main(), onde o programa começa a executar, tem o seguinte protótipo:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
```

A string argv[0] contém o nome do executável, as demais strings da matriz têm os demais parâmetros passados na linha de comando. O valor de argc corresponde ao comprimento de argv e geralmente não deve ser menor que 1, pois argv[0] sempre existe.